# Image can't be shown on OpenCV with Python

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, spyder

I am currently studying OpenCV using Anaconda. However, I get an error when I try showing a image.

The environments are: Anaconda3(Python 2.7.13), Windows 7, OpenCV 3.2.0

What I tried and the symptom is as following.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('sample',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
```

The error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow, fi
le C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\highgui\src
\window.cpp, line 304
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
cv2.error: C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\hig
hgui\src\window.cpp:304: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function
cv::imshow
```

Appreciate for your advice.

Comment: is your image really called `sample` with no suffix? I have no such issues if I supply the path to a valid image.

Comment: From the error, it tells the height and width of the image are not greater than 0 pixel. What's the acutal image source you typed in the code?

Comment: I added the suffix and it worked. Appreciate for the suggestions.
However, the window just keeps showing a grey image and it freezes when I click on it.
The size of this jpg image is 256×256.

Comment: I just put waitKey and successfully worked. Much appreciate for your helps.